# MongoDB use-case inventory

Tags: mongodb, concurrency, use-case

I am building an online retail store that has a fixed amount of clothes to sell obviously before its marked "sold-out". Assuming the traffic might get really high with clothes and other items selling out rapidly, I wanted to use MongoDB to track the inventory. However is this the best use-case for MongoDb.

How does MongoDB handle multiple updates to a single document.

In my case say there are 10 t-shirts, and 11 people come to the smae page to buy it. Now as there buying it, I check if the inventory is avaiable then perform an update decreasing the count. Will mongoDB queue the operations so that the update from a previous user is made and then the count is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking strictly to the 'use case' question, I think inventory management is something you'd traditionally look toward a transactional RDBMS for.  But it's not to say that MongoDB couldn't or wouldn't work fine (as others have already posted), just that it's not to my mind one of the hallmark features.

You might consider partitioning your business logic into two sections: site visits (presumably very high) and purchases/transactions (presumably some very small percentage of visits).  Then consider the benefits of distributed content delivery for the former, and transactional behavior for the latter.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB has a findandmodify function that will allow you to do an atomic update.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command

It should allow you to do

Comment: I just reread your question and this might not actually answer your question.  my bad.

Comment: I think `findAndModify` will work. You want to query for the inventory item with something like `{available: {$gt: 0}}`, and modify it with `{available: {$inc: -1}}`. The entire `findAndModify` is atomic, so if no inventory item (with matching name, id, whatever) exists with available count greater than 0, it will fail (and you can inform the user that it is sold out); else it will atomically modify the available count to "check out" the item to the user. Also see http://kylebanker.com/blog/2010/06/07/mongodb-inventory-transactions/ which has a lot of advice on this topic.